# Spring ConstraintValidator set custom code/rejected value

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I created a custom class-level ConstraintValidator that validates a certain field if another field has a specific value. Here's the object:

```
@ValidRequest
public class Request {

  interface ValidationName {}

  @NotBlank(groups = {Default.class})
  private final String fieldName;

  @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationName.class})
  @Length(max = 40, groups = {ValidationName.class})
  private final String fieldValue;

  // Constructor, getters
}
```

And the class-level ConstraintValidator:

```
public class ValidRequestImpl implements
  ConstraintValidator<ValidRequest, Request> {

  private Validator validator;

  @Autowired
  public ValidRequestImpl (Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(ValidRequest constraintAnnotation) {}

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(ValidRequest value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (!validator.validateProperty(value, "fieldName").isEmpty()) {
      return true;
    }
    if (value.getFieldName().equals("name")) {
      Set<ConstraintViolation<Request>> violations =
        validator.validateProperty(value, "fieldValue", ValidationName.class);
      violations.forEach(violation -> context
        .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessage())
        .addPropertyNode("fieldValue")
        .addConstraintViolation());
      context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
      return violations.isEmpty();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This works fine, but the returned errors object isn't very helpful:

```
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Please enter a name.",
    "field_name": "request.fieldValue",
    "rejected_value": "com.example.Request@5f017a8c",
    "code": "ValidRequest"
  }
],
```

Ideally, I would want the **rejected_value** field to be the actual fieldValue that was passed (in this case empty string), instead of the class-level object. I would also want the **code** field to be the actual annotation that failed (NotBlank), rather than ValidRequest. *context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate()* doesn't appear to have any methods that allow you to change these fields.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Remove @ValidRequest and you'll have it

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I need ValidRequest in order to do cross-field validation. My question is how to customize the error output given that I'm using a custom ConstraintValidator.

Comment: Ok let me give an answer for that

Comment: Have you find a way to do it?

Comment: did you find a way to modify code ?